# Setting up site-specific static folders with Django Sites

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-3.1

I am using Django Sites. I want to be able to have site-specific templates and static files.

My current directory structure is:

```
├── site_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── site_b
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── templates
    ├── site_a
    │   ├── _navbar.html
    │   ├── home.html
    │   └── signup.html
    └── site_b
        ├── _navbar.html
        ├── home.html
        └── signup.html
```

I know that I can move templates inside the site_x directory if I declare it as an app in INSTALLED_APPS. Is there another way to tell Django to use templates in site_a/templates without declaring site_a as an app?

Also, I would also like to have site specific static files that are not placed in the project STATIC_ROOT so that my tree actually looks like:

```
.
├── site_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── _navbar.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── site_b
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   └── js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── _navbar.html
    │   └── home.html
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setting static files via [**`STATICFILES_DIRS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)) **without** declaring  `site_a`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ('site_a', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site_a/static')),
    'Full path to your file or directory'
)
```

And in template:

```
<script src="{% static 'site_a/js/my_site_a.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

**And with declaring of your app:**

Store your [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)) in a folder called static in your app: **`site_a/static/site_a/example.jpg`**.

And for templates same: **`site_a/templates/site_a/example.html`**

in your settings.py set `APP_DIRS`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

See [Support for template engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines) and [Overriding templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/overriding-templates/):

> **APP_DIRS** tells whether the engine should look for templates inside installed applications. Each backend defines a conventional name for
> the subdirectory inside applications where its templates should be
> stored.

Comment: There is no need to include STATIC_ROOT (I guess that's what you mean by `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`) into STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, That is more as example, it can be anything. `os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static')` is basic static directory and for additional static you have to set full paths to your additional files directory(ies) e.g..

Comment: I know that I can register each new site as an app in INSTALLED_APPS. Is that the only way to make this happen? I'm wondering how that scales if I want to support 100 sites using SITE_ID but don't want to add 100 entries to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @Vishal, you can add any static file without register it, with other words you don’t need to add it in INSTALLED_APPS. Use `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: @Vishal, I have used site_a as example, to show that you can also add prefix for the additional directories.

Comment: I should have clarified. I was asking about the APP_DIRS only working for INSTALLED APPS but not directories within those INSTALLED APPS.

Comment: @Vishal, yes, APP_DIRS only working for installed apps.